# Макет в несколько столбцов с содержимым разной высоты

Tags: html, css, django

Здравствуйте!

Такая проблема:

Из базы данных приходит список новостей. Каждая новость — это картинка, заголовок и поясняющий текст. Все новости помещаются в несколько колонок (от 1 до 3 в зависимости от ширины окна). Все новости одинаковой ширины но разной длинны.

Нужно сверстать примерно такой макет:
[image: макет]

При этом нужно сохранить порядок новостей.

И вот не могу придумать, как такое сделать... Очень хочется без js. Используется django, шаблонизатор родной.

UPD: Если все-таки JS — к сайту прикручен JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А как насчет варианта с таблицами? Внешняя таблица имеет 3 столбца, а в эти столбцы добавляйте содержимое как хочется?

Comment: Я уже думал. И про три дива думал. Но проблема в том, что количество столбцов должно быть динамическим... на самом деле это, как я понял, единственное правитьное решение, но оно мне не подходит. В общем я сделал их более-менее квадратными и поставил  floaf: left; Но все равно спасибо =)

Comment: Насчет динамического: при использование любых шаблонов (хоть jQuery template), можно сделать пару шаблонов (3 или 2 столбца), и выбирать нужный в зависимости от ширины экрана

Answer (score 2):

На форуме htmlbook нашелся еще один вариант:

```css
.wrapper {
  line-height: 1em;
  columns: 200px auto;
  -moz-columns: 200px auto;
  -webkit-columns: 200px auto;
  break-after: column;
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #303;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.small {
  height: 200px;
}
.medium {
  height: 300px;
}
.big {
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="medium"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="medium"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="medium"></div>
</div>
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodeev/xqejP/)

Прядок новостей, правда, не сохраняется, но использовать можно. Спасибо zlodeev.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не воспользоваться каким-нибудь css фреймворком? Например, foundation. Вот как это сделать при помощи этого фреймворка:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="colunm large-4">
    <div>Блок 1</div>
    <div>Блок 4</div>
    <div>Блок 7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="colunm large-4">
    <div>Блок 2</div>
    <div>Блок 5</div>
    <div>Блок 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="colunm large-4">
    <div>Блок 3</div>
    <div>Блок 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не решит проблему. Во-первых, нужно было не переключение «три колонки-одна колонка», а динамическое число колонок. Во-вторых, посмотрите еще раз внимательно на ваш код. Это же ужасно — `Блок 1, Блок 4, Блок 7`... В третьих, когда это станет одной колонкой, порядок будет нарушен: `Блок 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 2 -> 5 -> ...`. Это плохо.

Comment: Сейчас бы я конечно использовал `flexbox`. Но в 13 году эта штука еще не было распространена.